# Installation error CUDA 5.5 on Nvidia gt 750m

Tags: cuda, gpu

While trying to install CUDA 5.5 on my windows 8.1 laptop NVidia Geforce GT 740M, I got the following error: I have also installed VS 2012 professional.

the graphics driver could not find compatible graphics  hardware. you may continue installation but you will not be able to run CUDA applications.

thanks

Comment: user55531, please accept the answer or indicate what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest driver for your GPU from nvidia.com.  Then install CUDA 6 (or CUDA 5.5), while deselecting the option to install the driver.

The driver that was included as part of the CUDA 5.5 install package is too old for your GPU.